# How to force flush ram after hibernate & suspend

Tags: suspend, ram, hibernate

There are methods to flush ram such as

```
(1) sudo sh -c "echo  3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

and

```
(2) sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a
```

and so on.

But I am curious, when a computer hibernates or suspends, ram is used to store information about the state.  I've read that while this happens with suspend, it is much more an issue with hibernate.

That being said, whether Ubuntu is flushing this temporary stored ram after the computer wakes up, or not , I would yet still like to know how to manually force a flush of this hibernated ram and also suspended ram, to reset my computer's ram to boot-state without the need to actually reboot.

I have found that the commands (1) and (2) do not actually do what I am trying to do.

After running

```
free -mh
htop
iotop
```

I can see that hibernated and suspended ram seems to be stored in a way that is not shown by htop and iotop.  free-mh seems to account for it but top commands do not.

I want the ability to target this stored ram specifically.